# PayPal Rest API gives 401 error when switched to Live Credentials

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal

I am creating a small website in which I implemented PayPal REST API to process Credit Card checkouts.

Now the problem is that it is working fine using Sandbox Credentials... but it gives following error when I switch to Live Credentials:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment. Retried 0 times.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\rest_api_sdk_php\sample\vendor\paypal\sdk-core-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection.php:99 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\rest_api_sdk_php\sample\vendor\paypal\sdk-core-php\lib\PayPal\Transport\PPRestCall.php(44): PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\rest_api_sdk_php\sample\vendor\paypal\rest-api-sdk-php\lib\PayPal\Api\Payment.php(246): PayPal\Transport\PPRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\rest_api_sdk_php\sample\payments\CreatePayment.php(89): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\rest_api_sdk_php\sample\vendor\paypal\sdk-core-php\lib\PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection.php on line 99

Quite frankly I have no idea what is causing this error. I made changes in two places when switching to PayPal Live. i.e.

1st in "bootstrap.php":

```
$apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential(
    '<Live Client ID>',
    '<Live Secret>'));
```

Gave Live Client-ID and Secret. And the other file in which I made change is "sdk_config.ini":

```
;Service Configuration
[Service]
mode=live ; can be set to sandbox / live
```

Changed "mode" from "sandbox" to "live"

Is there any other file also in which I have to make changes?

Comment: Can you confirm that it is actually trying to reach out to the correct Live endpoint?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick I don't know how to confirm this? Can you guide me?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick I am getting this in log file: `PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Connecting to https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment`. So, I guess it is reaching out to the correct Live EndPoint.

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Can you guide me what are the main possibilities of 401 error?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick The Last line of log file is this: `PayPal\Core\PPHttpConnection: Adding header PayPal-Request-Id: 36284914921976137475399828905`. Does this mean the credentials of Credit Card are going through fine?

Comment: Sorry. A 401 error usually means we weren't able to verify the credentials. So if you're submitting Live ones to the Sandbox endpoints you'd get a 401. Are you completing the OAuth step? You're using the SDK so you shouldn't be skipping it at all. Is it the most recent SDK?

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Yes, it is the recent SDK that I downloaded from this link: [paypal/rest-api-sdk-php](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php)

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Thanx buddy! I have resolved the issue. In fact the problem was not from my side. I was doing everything correctly. Client didn't enable her Live Account that's why I was unable to make payment requests using Live Credentials. Anyhow, thanx for your help!

Comment: @PayPal_Patrick Can you guide me what are the main possibilities of 401 error?

Comment: A problem I ran into: I had the mode in a config variable which I was using both for the SDK and the checkout.js env variable, when I switched the mode to 'live' the button dind't render until I realized that the SDK uses 'live' while checkout.js uses 'production'.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue then got solution.

You have to change the mode from `sandbox` to `live` and the `log.LogLevel` from `DEBUG` to `FINE` :

```
/* Sandbox */
$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'sandbox',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'DEBUG', // PLEASE USE FINE LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
        'cache.enabled' => true,
        // 'http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 30
        // 'http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id' => '123123123'
    )
);

/* For Live */
$apiContext->setConfig(
    array(
        'mode' => 'live',
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => '../PayPal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE', // PLEASE USE FINE LEVEL FOR LOGGING IN LIVE ENVIRONMENTS
        'cache.enabled' => true,
        // 'http.CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT' => 30
        // 'http.headers.PayPal-Partner-Attribution-Id' => '123123123'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

*Answer from the comments* - @PayPal_Patrick Thanx buddy! I have resolved the issue.

In fact the problem was not from my side. I was doing everything correctly.

Client didn't enable her Live Account that's why I was unable to make payment requests using Live Credentials. Anyhow, thanx for your help!